# Built-in for creating permutations of a character set of n length?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm aware of itertools.permutations(), but what I'm asking about is slightly different.

Given the character list:

```
["*", "/", "+", "-"]
```

Is there a built in that will create lists of the given characters of all permutations of N length?  So for example, if I wanted length 7:

```
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "/"]
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "+"]
  ... <after much processing> ...
["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "/"]
["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+"]
["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
```

As it stands, I wrote my own recursive procedure to generate them, but I'm sure there's some magic one line call I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is the cartesian product of 7 `["*", "/", "+", "-"]` lists. [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) takes a `repeat` argument for precisely this purpose:

```
for row in itertools.product(["*", "/", "+", "-"], repeat=7):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the `repeat` arg, e.g. `itertools.product(values, repeat=7)`?

Comment: That is exactly it.  I read through most of the itertools functions but Product() didn't stand out to me for some reason - thank you very much.